# Autowiring failed in spring mvc "Injection of autowired dependencies failed;"

Tags: spring, exception, model-view-controller, autowired

I am trying to autowire a field in spring mvc.But i got an exception:

"Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception"

I tried [Injection of autowired dependencies failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298610/injection-of-autowired-dependencies-failed)

But I'm still getting this Exception:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'careerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: DAO.CareerDAO controller.CareerController.cardao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DAO.CareerDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: DAO.CareerDAO controller.CareerController.cardao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DAO.CareerDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DAO.CareerDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml is:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="controller"></context:component-scan> 
        <context:component-scan base-package="bean"></context:component-scan>
        <context:component-scan base-package="DAO"></context:component-scan>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp" />
  <bean id="con" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intelliLABS"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>   
        <property name="password" value="root"></property> 

    </bean>

    <!--    normal jdbc template bean-->
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="con"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- For sending email,adding spring's mail support -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">  
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />  
        <property name="username" value="MYMAIL" />  
        <property name="password" value="MYPASSWORD" />  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>  
                <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailMail" class="bean.MailMail">  
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />  
    </bean>      

    <!--  this bean uses normal jdbc template -->
    <bean id="contactsDAO" class="DAO.ContactsDAO"> 
        <property name="jdbc" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

    <!--  this bean uses normal jdbc template -->
    <bean id="vacancyDAO" class="DAO.VacancyDAO"> 
        <property name="jdbc1" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

    <!--  this bean uses normal jdbc template -->
    <bean id="careerDAO" class="DAO.CareerDAO"> 
        <property name="jdbc2" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

Here are my classes :

```
package bean;

/**
 *
 * @author Anjana
 */
public class Career {

    int a_id;
    String name;
    String address;
    String email;
    String phone;
    String resumeDoc;
    int VacancyId;
    String dateApplied;

    //constructors

    public Career() {
    }

    public Career(int VacancyId) {
        this.VacancyId = VacancyId;
    }

    public Career(String name, String address, String email, String phone, String resumeDoc, int VacancyId, String dateApplied) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.resumeDoc = resumeDoc;
        this.VacancyId = VacancyId;
        this.dateApplied = dateApplied;
    }

    //getters

    public int getA_id() {
        return a_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getResumeDoc() {
        return resumeDoc;
    }

    public int getVacancyId() {
        return VacancyId;
    }

    public String getDateApplied() {
        return dateApplied;
    }

    //setters
    public void setA_id(int a_id) {
        this.a_id = a_id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setResumeDoc(String resumeDoc) {
        this.resumeDoc = resumeDoc;
    }

    public void setVacancyId(int VacancyId) {
        this.VacancyId = VacancyId;
    }

    public void setDateApplied(String dateApplied) {
        this.dateApplied = dateApplied;
    }



}
```

DAO class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package DAO;

import bean.Career;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;

/**
 *
 * @author Anjana
 */
public class CareerDAO {


    //injected
    JdbcTemplate jdbc2;

    //setter
    public void setJdbc2(JdbcTemplate jdbc2) {
        this.jdbc2 = jdbc2;
    }

    //methods to access database data

    //insertion
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public int insertion(Career car)
    {
       String insertQuery="insert into careers(name,address,email,phone,resumeDoc,vacancyId,dateApplied) values('"
                + car.getName()+ "','" + car.getAddress()+ "','"
                + car.getEmail()+ "','" + car.getPhone()+ "','"+ car.getResumeDoc()+ "','"
                + car.getVacancyId()+ "','" +car.getDateApplied()+ "')"; 
       return jdbc2.update(insertQuery);     
    }

    //deletion
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public int deletion(int a_id) {

        String deleteQuery = "delete from careers where id='" +a_id + "'";
        return jdbc2.update(deleteQuery);
    }

    //retrieve all to display
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List retrievedata() {

        String displayquery = "select * from careers";
        return jdbc2.query(displayquery, new ResultSetExtractor<List<Career>>() {

            @Override
            public List<Career> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

                List<Career> list = new ArrayList<>();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Career cr = new Career();
                    cr.setA_id(rs.getInt(1));
                    cr.setName(rs.getString(2));
                    cr.setAddress(rs.getString(3));
                    cr.setEmail(rs.getString(4));
                    cr.setPhone(rs.getString(5));
                    cr.setResumeDoc(rs.getString(6));
                    cr.setVacancyId(rs.getInt(7));
                    cr.setDateApplied(rs.getString(8));
                    list.add(cr);
                }

                return list;
            }
        });
    }

    //retrieve only one row
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------  
    public Career retrieveProfile(int a_id) {

        //returnig the details as an object of Career
        //using queryForObject() and BeanPropertyRowMapper

        String displayquery = "select * from careers where id=?";
        return jdbc2.queryForObject(displayquery, new Object[]{a_id}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Career>(Career.class));

    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package controller;

import DAO.CareerDAO;
import bean.Career;
import bean.MailMail;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author Anjana
 */
@Controller
public class CareerController {

    //inject objects of dao class
    @Autowired
    CareerDAO cardao;

    //inject objects of dao class
   // @Autowired
   // VacancyDAO Vdao;

    //inject objects of JavaMailSender class
    @Autowired
    private MailMail m;

    public CareerDAO getCardao() {
        return cardao;
    }

    public void setCardao(CareerDAO cardao) {
        this.cardao = cardao;
    }

    //go to careers page from index page
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    @RequestMapping("/careersPage")
    public ModelAndView ViewVacancyForPublic()
    {
       return new ModelAndView("redirect:/AllVacancies");
    }

    //go to Job Application Form 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping("/ApplicationForm")
    public ModelAndView Apply()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("careers/ApplicationForm","command",new Career());
    }       

    //Add applicant data
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

   @RequestMapping(value="/ApplySubmit",method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public ModelAndView AddApplication(@ModelAttribute Career career)
    {
       //get current date and time        
        DateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date=new Date();
        career.setDateApplied(dateformat.format(date).toString());

       //get login Id
       //int LoginId= ;
       //conta.setDelId(LoginId);

        if(cardao.insertion(career)==1)
        {

            //send mail to the person thanking him
            String from1="thisisanjusdummyacc@gmail.com";
            String to1 = career.getEmail();
            String sub1 = "Thanks";
            String msg1 = "Greetings from IntelliLABS!!\n"
                    + "We've received your job Application."
                    + "\nwe will get  back to you as soon as possible.";
              m.sendMail(from1, to1,sub1,msg1);

             //send mail to admin informing about the application received
            String from2="thisisanjusdummyacc@gmail.com";
            String to2 = "thisisanjusdummyacc@gmail.com";
            String sub2 = "New Job Application through IntelliLABS.com";
            String msg2 = "Hai Admin!!\n\n"
                    + "New job Application from "+career.getName()+"....\n\n"
                   // +"For the position : "+Vdao.retrieveVacancyTitle(career.getVacancyId())+"\n\n"
                    +"Login to the account to view the resume."
                    + "And Please reply as soon as possible\n"
                    +"to the mail : "+career.getEmail();
            // sends the e-mail
            m.sendMail(from2, to2,sub2,msg2);

            //display a message or alert saying "thank you for connecting with us"
            System.out.println("insertion successful");
        }
        else{
        //else display "application failed...try agin later in alert"
            System.out.println("insertion failed");
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/AllVacancies");

    }

     //display all applicants to only admin
     //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping("/ShowApplicants")
    public ModelAndView DispAllApplicants()
    {

        List<Career> profileList= cardao.retrievedata(); 
        return new ModelAndView("admin/ViewProfiles","profileList",profileList);

    }

   //delete applicant only by admin
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------   

    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteProfile/{a_id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteProfile(@PathVariable int a_id)
    {

        if(cardao.deletion(a_id)==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Profile "+a_id+" deleted\n");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/ShowApplicants");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/failiure");
        }

    }

    //show one profile for admin
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------   

    @RequestMapping(value="/dispProfile/{a_id}")
    public ModelAndView viewOneProfile(@PathVariable int a_id)
    {
         Career prof= cardao.retrieveProfile(a_id);

         return new ModelAndView("admin/ApplicantProfile","command",prof);
    } 




}
```

can someone help me to understand this autowiring problem...

Comment: i'd recommend not mixing XML and annotations.

Comment: did you mean i should either use @autowiring annotation for injecting bean class to Dao class ,or use xml based injection for injecting dao class to contoller class ?

Comment: i'd get rid of the XML and do the component scanning and configuration programmatically.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark your Dao layer bean  with stereotype (i.e Repository or Component) annotation such as below:

```
@Repository
public class CareerDAO {

//injected
JdbcTemplate jdbc2;

// rest of your logic
}
```

Spring component scanning scans the given packages and look for stereotype annotations such as @Component, @Service and create those beans and inject it into appropriate beans. since you have not marked the bean with those annotation, spring have not created the dao bean.